# iOS - How to get a time interval in a picker view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I want to set a time interval in one picker view. How can I manage two time pickers in one picker view? One for a starting time and one for the ending time?

You can see what I mean in the screenshot.

[Screenshot of the design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFzSi.png)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why don't you use two different `pickerviews` for two different actions, e.g one for your starting time and one for your ending time. @Henning

Comment: Put two `UIDatePicker`, and when one change, set the min or max date accordingly to the other one?

Comment: Because the designer had the great idea to do it in one line. ;-) @iPeter

Comment: We all face that problem LOL ;) @Henning

Comment: How can I do this? Do you have a short example? @Larme

Comment: Refer this link that may help you : https://github.com/scheinem/MSCTimeSpanPicker